# How to go to label in called batch file

Tags: batch-file

My code is like this in **one.bat:**

```
@echo off
    echo hi
    call example.bat
:label
    echo hello
    pause
```

My code is like this in **example.bat:**

```
@echo off
    echo hi!
    call one.bat
```

I want it to goto the label once one.bat is called. How do I do this?

Comment: what you are doing: start one. Call example, which calls one, which calls example wich calls one wich calls....  Replace `call one.bat`in your example.bat with `goto :eof`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return to the line below where you called example.bat (place where you currently have the label) , you don't need the label. Use exit /b at end of example.bat.

```
@echo off
    echo hi!
    exit /b
    :: Takes you back to the batch file at the spot you left it
```

If you *really do* want to go to a label in one.bat, put `goto %1` at the top of **one.bat** (right under @echo off) and pass a variable with the name of the label when you do the call. Like this:

```
@echo off
    echo hi!
    set gotoPlace=label
    call one.bat %gotoPlace%
```

Calling One.bat starts it over again, but the variable you are passing to One.bat (%gotoplace%) replaces the %1 that you put at the top of the file, so "goto %1" now equals "goto label".

**Edit:** %1 used this way does what you want in your very simple batch file, but typically you wouldn't want `goto %1` at the top of a bat. The beginning of *[this page](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)* tells more about passing items from one batch file to another.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with contrived code is that the answer to the question may not be what you are looking for :)

```
@echo off
echo hi
echo hi!
start "" "%comspec%" /c one.bat
echo hello
pause
```